# Python Ursina, How can I get the players position?

Tags: python

The title says it all, how can I get a the first person camera controller's position (X, Y, Z) in Python using the Ursina Game Engine?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `camera.position` to get the player's position. If you're using the `FirstPersonController`, you can simply do :

```py
controller = FirstPersonController()
controller.position
```

Since FirstPersonController is an entity.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `entity.position`. You can get the position of every entity, including the player.

Make.

```py
player = Entity(model='cube', position=(0,10,0)

player_pos = player.position
print(player_pos)
```

Because position is an attribute of Entity, you can get that value and print it.

## Bonus

You can change the player to FPC and you will get the same result.